# Code used to work but now ggplot comes up empty

Tags: r, ggplot2

Last year I made a code that plotted means and standard deviations. When I tried using the code again today a warning message is coming up:

```
Warning messages:
1: Removed 224 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
2: Removed 224 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
```

The plot appears with no points or lines. I find it weird because the code used to work properly previously. Can you please help me find out what is wrong in the code and how I can fix it now?

[image]

```
library(readxl)
IRcombined <- read_excel("IRcombined.xlsx")
View(IRcombined)
attach(IRcombined)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
i<- ggplot(data=IRcombined, aes(x=Night, y=Ingestionrate, colour=factor(Condition), shape=factor(Condition)))
i1<- i + scale_shape_manual(values = c(1,16),name="Condtion",breaks=c("Healthy","Bleached"))+ scale_color_manual(values=c("dark grey", "black"),name="Condtion",breaks=c("healthy","bleached"))+
  facet_grid(Species ~ fct_rev(Particletype))+ 
  stat_summary(fun="mean", geom="point", size = 2, position=position_dodge(width =0.90)) + stat_summary(fun="mean", geom="line", size = 0.8, position=position_dodge(width =0.90))+
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl, fun.args=list(mult=1), geom= 
                 "errorbar", position=position_dodge(width=0.90), width=0.52) + scale_x_discrete(limits=c(1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28)) +
  labs(x=expression(Time~ (Night)), y=expression(Average ~ingestion ~rate ~ (particles~polyp^{-1}~h^{-1}))) + 
  theme_bw()+ theme(legend.justification = "top")+ theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black"))

i2<- i1 + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) + 
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill="white"))+ scale_fill_discrete(breaks=c("AI","PV"))+ theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8, vjust = -0.25, color = "black")) + theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=8, hjust=1, color="black")) 
print(i2)


> dput(head(IRcombined))
 structure(list(Condition = c("Bleached", "Bleached", "Bleached", 
 "Bleached", "Bleached", "Bleached"), Species = c("PV", "PV", 
 "PV", "PV", "PV", "PV"), Particletype = c("Mix", "Mix", "Mix", 
 "Mix", "Mix", "Mix"), Subject = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Night = c(1, 
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Ingestionrate = c(2.78, 2.93, 1.62, 2.83, 2.14, 
 2.76)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
 ))
```

Comment: If the _exact same_ code worked before and doesn't work now, then I strongly suspect your data has changed in some way. There is no overt error in your code as such. Without seeing your data, there is no way anyone here can help you. Perhaps edit your question with the results of `dput(IRcombined)`, or if that is too large, `dput(head(IRcombined))`

Comment: You could try `skim` from the `skimr` package to look for data problems. `skim(IRcombined)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have tried skim(IRcombined) now and everything seems fine with my data, all the observations are there. So I'm really not sure what the issue is

Comment: R is sensitive to capitalization. Your variable `Condition` has values of "Bleached" and "Healthy" but you specified "bleached" and "healthy" in your color scale. Because your data are capitalized, they are coded as missing. To fix, change `scale_color_manual(values=c("dark grey", "black"),name="Condtion",breaks=c("healthy","bleached"))` to `scale_color_manual(values=c("dark grey", "black"),name="Condtion",breaks=c("Healthy","Bleached"))`

Comment: Thank you so much, Joel Schneider! I tried it now, and it worked perfectly.